# What is the next step in this proof? Am I even on the right track? Multivariable Inverse Function Inequalities

Tags: real-analysis

We have a question to show a series of three inequalities related to the Inverse Function Theorem. I'm just asking about the first, most straightforward one, which may not actually need the IFT (I think it's a foundational question for the other two that do use the IFT).

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}\newcommand{\bvec}[1]{\textbf{#1}}$
Let $A$ be an open set in $\R^n$, $x_0\in A$, and let $f:A\to\R^m$ be differentiable at $x_0$. Prove the following claims, see Theorem 1.89 (This is the inverse function theorem).

For any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a neighborhood $U_{x_0}$ of $x_0$ such that $$|f(x)-f(x_0)|\leq \left(\|\bvec{D}f(x_0)\|+\epsilon\right)|x-x_0|$$

**My first steps:**
*This reminded me of the proof used in my book for the IFT, which referenced the multivariable version of the mean value theorem, which states:*

**Mean Value Theorem Corollary:** Let $f:B(x_0,r)\subset\R^n\to\R^m$ be a map that has directional derivatives at every point of $B(x_0,r)$ and let $K:=\text{sup}\left\{\|\textbf{D}f(z)\|:z\in B(x_0,r)\right\}$. Then $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq K|x-y|$.

*The proof of this is similar to my approach to the main problem, so I'll just show how I approached the main problem.*

By the Integral form of the Mean Value Theorem,

\begin{align*}|f(x)-f(x_0)|&\leq \left|\int_0^1\textbf{D}f(x_0+t(x-x_0))(x-x_0)dt\right|\\
&\leq\int_0^1 |\textbf{D}f(x_0+t(x-x_0))(x-x_0)dt|\\
&\leq\int_0^1 \|\textbf{D}f(x_0+t(x-x_0))\|dt|x-x_0|
\end{align*}

And that's where I'm stuck. In the proof of of the corollary, the next conclusion is that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|\leq K|x-x_0|$, but in my case, I don't want to go straight to the supremum. But I'm not sure how to show that $\int\|\textbf{D}f(x_0+t(x-x_0))dt\|\leq\|\textbf{D}f(x_0)-\epsilon\|$

Comment: Just use the definition of the derivative: $\left \| \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)-Df(x_0)h}{h} \right \|<\epsilon $ where $h=x-x_0$ is small enough so that the inequality holds.

Comment: Thanks! That worked out well. If you post that as the answer, I will accept it as the correct one, unless there's a reason you didn't. I'm new here, so still learning the etiquette. Should I post my final result myself?

Comment: When I edit my own answers, I usually post the edits, so others can see what my process was. I will be happy to post my comment as an answer. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the definition of the derivative, namely, $\left \| \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)-Df(x_0)h}{h} \right \|<\epsilon$ where $h=x−x_0$ is small enough so that the inequality holds.