# How do I show this inequality re: the inverse function theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

This is a continuation of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2955361/what-is-the-next-step-in-this-proof-am-i-even-on-the-right-track-multivariable).

I have the problem to show that 
$$\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|\geq\left(\frac{1}{\|\textbf{D}f(x_0)^{-1}\|}-\epsilon\right)|x-y|.$$

The book gives the hint: If $L=\textbf{D}f(x_0)$ then $|s-t|=L^{-1}(Ls-Lt)\leq\|L^{-1}\||Ls-Lt|$.

What I've tried:
Based on the hint, I did the following:
\begin{equation}
|x-y|\leq\|L^{-1}\||L||x-y|\tag{1}
\end{equation}

We had from a previous part of the problem that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq(\|\textbf{D}f(x_0)\|+\epsilon)|x-y|$, so I really wanted to somehow substitute $|f(x)-f(y)|$ into the right side of (1) to get

\begin{equation}
|x-y|\leq\|L^{-1}\||f(x)-f(y)|
\end{equation}

This would allow me to show the requested expression...except the statement isn't true, and I have no epsilon, but the equations are tantalizingly close. I'm not sure how to use the hint or how to get from what I have to what I need.

How can I connect the hint to my expression and/or get epsilon in the position I need?

EDIT:
The problem references the inverse function theorem, though I'm not sure how to apply it in this case, except to establish that the inverse function does indeed exist. However, I'm not sure if that theorem should apply to the derivative, which is the only inverted function that appears in the problem so far.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've come up with. I'd like some feedback on its correctness though, so I'll leave it open to voting for a while.

Let $f(x_0)=y_0$. Then, by the Inverse Function Theorem, there is a neighborhood about $y_0$ such that $\textbf{D}f^{-1}(f(x_0))=\textbf{D}f(x_0)^{-1}$.

Then by part (b) we have
    \begin{equation}\label{eq2}
\left|f^{-1}(f(x))-f^{-1}(f(y))\right|\leq(\|\textbf{D}f(x_0)^{-1}\|+\epsilon')|f(x)-f(y)|
\end{equation}
    where $\epsilon'=\frac{\|\textbf{D}f(x_0)\|^2}{1-\epsilon\|\textbf{D}f(x_0)\|}\epsilon$. Then $\|\textbf{D}f(x_0)\|+\epsilon'=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\|\textbf{D}f(x_0)\|}-\epsilon}$.
    Then \ref{eq2} becomes
        \begin{equation*}
|x-y|\leq\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\|\textbf{D}f(x_0)\|}-\epsilon}\right)|f(x)-f(y)|
\end{equation*}

Some algebra gives
    \begin{equation*}
|f(x)-f(y)|\geq\left(\frac{1}{\|\textbf{D}f(x_0)\|}-\epsilon\right)|x-y|
\end{equation*}